# Does the xdmp:http module in MarkLogic support PATCH request?

Tags: marklogic

According to the documentation (https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:http-get), the supported methods are GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, and OPTIONS. Why is PATCH missing?

Comment: I don't know why it's not there, but you're correct that it's not there. A custom REST extension is likely the best approach for your use case.

Comment: @rjrudin Thanks for confirming!